# How do I get NHibernate to save an entity if I assign it an ID, but generate one otherwise?

Tags: nhibernate, rest, fluent-nhibernate, nhibernate-mapping, identity

According to the REST philosophy, a `PUT` request should update the resource at a URL if it exists, and create it if it doesn't exist. So in other words, if I use the following URL:

```
PUT http://server/item/5
```

If an `Item` exists with an ID of 5, it will be updated. If an `Item` doesn't exist with an ID of 5, a new `Item` will be created with an ID of 5.

However, I'm using NHibernate for persistence, and I mapped my IDs as `Identity`. This means that no matter what value I assign the ID, NHibernate will replace it with its own when I save a new `Item`.

How do I get NHibernate to save an `Item` with the ID that I assign it, without changing the ID mapping to `Assigned`?

Comment: you are wrong on the assumption that identity mapped ids are generated by nhibernate. for SQL Server for example its an extra round-trip

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you use Identity, the DB won't allow you to enter a value.

That said, if your DB has some special syntax to allow inserting with explicit values in Identity fields, you can implement your own generator, which I guarantee will be error prone, hard to debug, and not very useful. But it's possible.

Study everything in https://nhibernate.svn.sourceforge.net/svnroot/nhibernate/trunk/nhibernate/src/NHibernate/Id and start creating your Frankenstein :-)

Comment: What about the case where the datatype is `int` on the database, but it's NHibernate that's preventing the manually-assigned ID from being used?