# How do I create an entity through a RESTful PUT with NHibernate?

Tags: c#, nhibernate, rest, fluent-nhibernate, identity

According to REST philosophy, a PUT operation should **create** an entity if it doesn't exist, or **update** it if it does. So for example, if a client does this operation:

```
PUT http://server/user/5?firstname=John&lastname=Doe
```

I should expect that a user with an ID of 5 either be created or updated.

The **update** case is easy with NHibernate; simply retrieve the user and update the firstname and lastname.

However, how do I **create** a user with an ID of 5? By default, NHibernate manages all entity IDs. Even if you set the ID yourself, NHibernate will ignore it and replace it with its own. If I switch to using assigned IDs, then I can assign a new user with an ID of 5, but then I'd lose a lot of NHibernate's features.

So in other words, is there a way to configure NHibernate to use a generated ID if one is not provided, and to use the user-set ID if one is provided? If not, how do I get around this problem of PUT creation with NHibernate?

Comment: Interesting, we have the same issue (well concern) with EntityFramework. It's almost like you need to programatically set `IDENTITY_INSERT` on. Interested to see if you find an answer. +1

Comment: Good question. Just out of curiosity, where does the ID of 5 come from if the user hasn't been created yet? It seems you're saying that you want you user to have that ID, but you don't know what IDs are available yet.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do I get NHibernate to save an entity if I assign it an ID, but generate one otherwise?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3886877/how-do-i-get-nhibernate-to-save-an-entity-if-i-assign-it-an-id-but-generate-one)

Comment: How is this question different from your previous one?

Comment: @Diego: It's not, but I thought maybe asking again in a different way would elicit different answers. This seems like one of those fundamental issues that should have been solved many times over, and yet I can't seem to find any answers. Every time I ask the question, I get several upvotes and stars, so it seems like an issue that other people are concerned with as well.

Comment: @DaveDev: The thought is that after the initial `POST` and the client gets the ID, someone on the server might've deleted it. When the client tries a `PUT` to update it, it might not exist. Rather than forcing the client to do a `POST` again to recreate it, they can just do a `PUT` and the server will create the entity as if it was never deleted, with the same ID.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you do a

```
PUT http://server/user/5
```

and the server creates the object but nHibernate changes the id then, return the HTTP status code `301 - Moved permanently` and put the new URI in the Location header.

The client should detect the 301 and update any stored URLs with the old Id.

Just a word of warning, PUT semantics are not really Create and Update, they are replace.  So if you send a representation that contains just last name and first name, then if you do things by the book, then all other information that was previously stored about that user is lost.